# IE8 not recognizing css :hover properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hover

I have a series of icons in my navigation. They should appear white by default, blue on hover. When the icon is clicked it gets an 'active' class assigned at which point it should still be white by default, but also white on hover.

In IE8 after class 'active' is assigned it stays blue, regarles of hover. I have this doctype on my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.appNav div {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.appNav div:hover {
    color: blue;
}
.appNav div.active {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.appNav div.active:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Edit: as rink.attendant.6 asked, I'm using fontawesome for my icons, so they're font text icons.

Comment: Are the icons images or fonts (text)?

Comment: I'm using fontawesome for the icons, so it's an imported font. Good question - I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Could you maybe do a real simple example in a jsfiddle with just a couple links and your imported font with this CSS?

Comment: what kind of container holds class="appNav" ? An html5 container like 'nav' ?

Comment: Have you checked that the `className` of the div was really changed? May be it's better to set different color for `.appNav div.active` during debugging?

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NZXV/) that demonstrates your (working) code.

Comment: @MilchePatern - a div holds it.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn - yep, I am also changing the background color when the active class gets added. I took that out here for clairity. (I tested with the code I posted too though, and it still doesn't work in case your wondering whether the stripped CSS could be affecting it).

Comment: @AndréDion - Thanks! Unfortunately JS Fiddle doesn't seem to be working in IE8 so testing is impossible.

Comment: @Henry - JSfiddle works fine in IE8.  There is obviously something wrong with your system.  Have you checked for viruses or malware?

Comment: @Henry, I supposed that the problem could be in the Javascript part that adds `.active` class, not in the CSS itself. But if you say that the class change has visible effect, my guess seems to be wrong.

Comment: about to downvote for 'lack of information' and a decent css-html-javascript working example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason this should not work in IE 8

> The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element
>   with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.

See : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act for details.

[Also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> Starting with Windows Internet Explorer 7, when the browser is in
>   standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE), you can apply the :hover
>   pseudo-class to any element, not only links. If the pseudo-class is
>   not applied specifically to an element in the selector, such as the a
>   tag, the Universal (*) Selector is assumed. Indiscriminate use of the
>   :hover pseudo-class can negatively impact page performance.

Still you could [force IE to :hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html) on any elements and manage IE erratic support of :hover. But this is from the past.

This 'buggy' and not clear context invited developers to use javascript to achieve a better cross-browser behavior with jQuery.

Also, i see your doctype is html5. Did you htmlShim you page ?

Comment: The statement that `:hover` is _only_ for links not true according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act). Browsers newer than IE6 don't have such limitations.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn You're right, just couldn't finish editing answer fast enough.

Comment: @MilchePatern The htmlShim doesn't seem to help. Just tried it. And neither does a strict doctype.